# Converter todo banco mysql para minúscula

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, phpmyadmin

É possível *converter* todas as colunas das tabelas de um banco de dados *mysql* para letras minúsculas?

Tenho vários registros e várias tabelas, todas estão uma miscelânea de maiúsculas e minúsculas (e algumas com acentuação).

Detalhe: o tipo é *InnoDB*; *collation* está definido como *utf8_bin*.

Comment: update Tabela SET valor = LOWER(valor)

Comment: @Gustavo, publiquei uma resposta, veja se ajuda. Eu não tinha visto ainda algo desse tipo.. deu um trabalhinho legal, mas gostei do código =]

Comment: vc quer converter o nome da coluna ou o valor?

Comment: @rray os valores!

Comment: @rLinhares não funcionou...

Comment: @GustavoMacielSetta viu se deu algum erro ou se atualizou algum dado? chegou a olhar o _fiddle_?

Comment: @rLinhares o fiddle não funcionou. E no meu banco tbm não, diz que não existe a tabela tabela_tmp. Criei a tabela com as mesmas colunas mas continuou apresentando erro...

Comment: @rLinhares o fiddle não estava funcionando. Mas chequei agora e ele está ok, contudo não faço a menor ideia de como aplicar essa sua solução para meu banco, ou seja, continuo na mesma...

Comment: qual o problema com o banco? por que não consegue aplicar??

Answer (score 1):

Não conheço nenhuma forma "simples" de fazer isso, mas através desse algoritmo acredito que terá o resultado esperado:

```
SET @row_number := 0;

INSERT INTO tabela_tmp
SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS num, CONCAT('update ', TABLE_NAME, ' SET ', CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME, '=LOWER(', COLUMN_NAME, ')')), ';'))
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
GROUP BY TABLE_NAME;

SET @id_tabela:=1, @total:=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabela_tmp);

WHILE @id_tabela <= @total DO
    SET @comando = (SELECT comando FROM tabela_tmp where num = @id_tabela);

    PREPARE myquery FROM @comando;
    EXECUTE myquery;

    SET @id_tabela = @id_tabela + 1;    
END WHILE;
```

`tabela_tmp` é uma tabela que armazenará os comandos de atualização de cada tabela (um em cada linha). Na montagem desse *comando*, utilizei o [`CONCAT()`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_concat.asp) para a estrutura ("*update tabela ...*") e [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/) para pegar todos os campos da tabela e organizá-los em uma linha.
Feito isso, em um *loop* basta carregar os comandos e executá-los.

[**Exemplo funcionando**](https://rextester.com/OZX75939)